# How to find device by device ID and vendor ID?

Tags: installation, drivers, vendor-id

I bought a new Dell laptop which was not pre-installed (OS-less). I'm now downloading drivers from Dell's site, but for each category there's a selection and I'm not sure which drivers I should download.

Through device manager \ right click on an unknown device \ properties - I was able to find the device ID and vendor ID of each device. I used [this site](http://www.pcidatabase.com/) and also [this site](http://pciids.sourceforge.net/) to try to find out what's what, but it seems its database is not complete.

What other resources\sites can I use to identify devices using their device\vendor ID?

Answer (score 4):

[Unknown Device Identifier](http://www.zhangduo.com/udi.html) is the best tool I've used for tracking down drivers when I needed more information about a device.

Answer (score 2):

[The PCI ID Repository](http://pciids.sourceforge.net/)

[USB IDs](http://www.linux-usb.org/usb.ids)

Comment: I've added your first link to the question in parallel to you :) The second link is nice though